# How could the hacker tamper with the 'configuration.php' file in my Joomla web server?

Tags: web-application, webserver, intrusion

I have a web server hosting Joomla 1.5. I discovered that the Joomla configuration file `configuration.php` was modified by a hacker. How could he do so?

Note that the file has `777` permission. Also, when I try to directly browse the file `www.mysite.com/configuration.php` I get an empty page as a response.

Comment: Please, read about [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Symbolic_modes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the 777 permission means that the configuration file you are talking about [can be edited by any other user on the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Octal_numbers). So basically, a hacker who compromises your server and gets operating system access has the required permissions to tamper that file.

A hacker can compromise your server and get system access simply by exploiting a vulnerable service running on your server, like old unpatched versions of Samba or FTP.

He could also exploit a vulnerability within your web server or your PHP installation to gain remote code execution privileges. As an example, take a look at this [PHP CGI bug](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve-details.php?cve_id=CVE-2012-1823) which [can be easily exploited using the free open source Metasploit Framework](http://www.metasploitminute.com/2012/05/cve-2012-1823-php-cgi-bug.html).

Most likely, the hacker changed your configuration file by exploiting [a vulnerability in your Joomla installation](http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_description=&filter_exploit_text=Joomla%201.5&filter_author=&filter_platform=0&filter_type=0&filter_lang_id=0&filter_port=&filter_osvdb=&filter_cve=). By the time of this writing, the latest Joomla 1.5.x series update [is 1.5.26](http://www.joomla.org/download.html). Is your Joomla installation fully updated?

If you want to trace the hacker's activity a good starting point would be inspecting your log files, assuming of course that the hacker did not cover his traces and tampered these as well.

Answer (score 0):

How was it possible for someone to modify a file which is writeable by *any user on the system*? Most likely a local file inclusion bug (which are rather common with Joomla plugins)